# 70MB memory with images and 18 ViewControllers sdk

Tags: iphone, memory-management, sdk, uiimageview, viewcontroller

I am developing an application like a book with pictures and motion. I have 18 views, each view is more real memory (max 70MB).

images of development with this code:

```
fonsImatge = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fons_pis.png", 0] ofType:nil]]];
    [fonsImatge setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
    fonsImatge.alpha = 1.0f;
    //[UIView commitAnimations];
    [self.view insertSubview:fonsImatge atIndex:0];
    [fonsImatge release];


letra_a = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lletra_a_01.png"]];
    [letra_a setFrame:CGRectMake(406, 114, 270, 318)];
    [self.view insertSubview:letra_a atIndex:2];
    [letra_a release];  
    letra_a.alpha = 0.0;
    letra_a.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"lletra_a_01.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"lletra_a_02.png"],nil];
    letra_a.animationDuration = 5.00;
    letra_a.animationRepeatCount = 1000;
    [letra_a startAnimating];
```

next views:

```
proj_lletrac_fosca *viewController = [[proj_lletrac_fosca alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    [viewController release];


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.fonsSemi=nil;
    self.fletra_a=nil;
}
```

How I can remove the memory of the previous view?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using, and are you using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting)?

Comment: My Xcode is 4.2.1, I don't using ARC

Comment: I would give it a try, it is responsible for automatically releasing anything allocated, which will really help with your memory problem.

Comment: I have a problem. main.m - 'NSAutoreleasePool' is unavailable: not aviable in automatic reference counting mode

Answer (score 1):

In short, you don't explicitly do it. You should implement `viewDidUnload` in all your view controllers and release anything that can be created again in `viewDidLoad`. Then UIKit will do the right thing and unload views which are not on screen when memory is getting tight.

Comment: - (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.fonsSemi=nil;
    self.fletra_a=nil;
}